# Issue in google map app redirection using openURL

Tags: ios

I have an issue with google map. In my device, not installed Google map but still, I am getting success. Is there any issue?????

```
@IBAction func clickedBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let customURL = "comgooglemaps://"

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: customURL)!) {

        print("Success")
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: customURL)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Google maps not installed", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(ok)
        self.present(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I also added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that's success result?

Comment: I debug code if condition is always right.

Comment: Do you have installed google chrome?

Comment: Google chrome not installed on my device.